# Scala get html content from web page

Tags: html, scala

I am trying to get a whole html from a website in scala and then parse or get out certain information out of it. 
The standard html library doesnt work for me as if I am trying to print the html content it doesnt print the whole html?
Any solutions how to get a full html content from a web page?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Well you could use the excellent scala-scraper library [here](https://github.com/ruippeixotog/scala-scraper) :
Its basically a wrapper for the JSoup Java library
You could write code that reads like this :(taken from GitHub)

```
object NewsApp extends App {
  val browser = JsoupBrowser()
  val doc = browser.get("http://observador.pt")

  println()
  println("=== OBSERVADOR ===")

  doc >> extractor(".logo img", attr("src")) |> println
  doc >> extractorAt[String]("example-extractor") |> println

  println("==================")
  println()

  doc >> ".small-news-list h4 > a" foreach println
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your advice! I will take a look at this library!

Comment: I have no idea how to install this library in Replit... https://replit.com/@RixTheTyrunt/Croissant?v=1

Answer (score 0):

How are you getting html page in Scala ?
I think you can look at spray-client http://spray.io/documentation/1.2.3/spray-can/http-client/